# PHP regex alphanumeric bounded by nonalpha numeric

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get all occurrences of

> @something

bounded by any nonalphanumeric character or space.

I tried

> [^A-Za-z0-9\s]*@(\S*)[^A-Za-z0-9]

but it keeps including space after word.

I'll be glad for any help, thanks.

Edit:
So issue would be clear, I want to get match from

> Line start @word1 something @word2,@word3

all '@word1', '@word2', '@word3'

Comment: @\w+ wouldnt do the trick?

Comment: Thanks! That seems working! Turns out to be really simple :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
@\w+
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?33gt4)

```
preg_match_all('#(@\w+)#', 'Line start @word1 something @word2,@word3', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Taking from Madbreak comment, to exclude `@` preceded by any character, use this instead

```
 (?<!\w)@\w+(?=\b)
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?33gts)

Comment: @KillerFrca This will match `@` preceeded by alphanumeric characters, which your question stated was not acceptable.

Comment: @Madbreaks i added look asertion to exclude `@` preceded by any alphanumeric character

Answer (score 0):

This

```
preg_match_all('/[^@]*@(\S*)/', 'blabla @something1 blabla @something2 blabla', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => something1
    [1] => something2
)
```

Comment: `[^@]` will match alphanumeric characters